# preg_replace_callback is not matching when multiline

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi i have the following preg_replace_callback which i use in my template system to  execute code inside **{{** php code goes here **}}**

```
preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/', function($match) {
    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($match);
    echo "</pre>";  
}, $string);
```

when code is single line

```
$string = '{{ echo "Hello"; }}'
```

its working fine and the dump result is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "{{ echo "Hello"; }}"
  [1]=>
  string(15) " echo "Hello"; "
}
```

but when the code is multline

```
$string = '{{ 
echo "Hello"; 
echo " My name is Ntan"; 
}}'
```

i get no dump results because it's not matching

Can anyone help me plz

Comment: You need to use the multi-line switch `/m` if you want to use a multi-line regexp - http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @MarkBaker: m modifier (multiline) only changes anchors (`^`, `$`) meaning, the s modifier (for *singleline* <= the name is a bit counter-intuitive) allows the dot to match newlines. (and in Ruby the m modifier allows the dot to match newlines and don't change anchors meaning)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Thanks for the clarification, I'll have to remember it for some of my own regexp use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `s` modifier that forces dot to match newline:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/s', function($match) {
    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($match);
    echo "</pre>";  
}, $string);
```